# Why doesn't my program read my file that was created using the same program?

Tags: java, file, file-io

I'm trying to create a program that makes a file that randomly generates numbers and I want the program to read those numbers off of the file and analyze it. If the randomly generated number doesn't equal 0, the program should keep generating numbers, but if it does equal 0, then the program will stop. However, it seems that my program is not reading those numbers.

I tried putting the `outFile.close();` and `inFile.close();` in a couple different places to see if that would fix anything, but it seems that didn't work out. I tried tracing my code with pen and paper, but I couldn't find anything wrong. Perhaps it could be my placement of `outFile.close();` and `inFile.close();`, but I couldn't find anything wrong with it.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class squirrel {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("squirrel.txt"));
    Scanner inFile =  new Scanner(new File("squirrel.txt"));
    Random rand = new Random();
    int squirrelNum;
    int foxSquirrel = 0;
    int squirrelsSeen = 0;
    int trials = 0;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Fox Squirrel Simulator\n");
    System.out.println("How many trials should be simulated?");
    System.out.println("Enter a value greater than 1000: ");
    trials = in.nextInt();

    while(trials <= 1000)
    {
        System.out.println("Please try again. Enter a value greater than 1000: ");
        trials = in.nextInt();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= trials; i ++)
    {
        squirrelNum = rand.nextInt(10);
        outFile.println(squirrelNum);

        while(inFile.hasNextInt())
        {
            int token = inFile.nextInt();

            while(token != 0)
            {

                squirrelsSeen ++;
            }

            if(token == 0)
            {
                foxSquirrel ++;
                squirrelsSeen ++;
            }
            outFile.close();
        }


        System.out.println("squirrelsSeen: " + squirrelsSeen);
        System.out.println("foxSquirrel: " + foxSquirrel);
    }


    inFile.close();
    System.out.println("\nsimulating trials now... one moment please...\n");
    System.out.println("The results!");
    System.out.println("The average number of squirrels until spotting a Fox Squirrel at the city park is: " + (((double)foxSquirrel / squirrelsSeen) * 100));



 }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure inFile and outFile points to the same file, maybe they are two files with the same name? Not sure how this works since I haven’t worked with files like this before. Off topic but your code makes no sense to me, why write a line to a file and then read it directly? The logical solution would have been to skip that file altogether.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure they point to the same file. It's part of my school assignment. I have to create a file and then read the data off that same file.

Comment: "_Yes, I'm sure they point to the same file._" If you can't read from the file then how exactly did you confirm this statement?

Comment: Maybe you need to close or at least flush the file before reading it

Comment: We haven't learned how to flush yet. I think the main problem is where I place the outFile.close(); , however I'm not sure where it should go.

Comment: Shouldn't you create the entire outfile first, then set the infile equal to the outfile and analyze it then?

Comment: The outfile depends on whether infile scans 0 or not so I wouldn't think that would work.

Comment: Are you sure you have understood the exercise correctly? This write one line/ read one line logic seems so wrong.

Answer (score 2):

And here is how it is done using Scanner.

```
File file = new File("squirrel.txt");

    try {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            int i = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        sc.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And it is like you said. You put the .close() inside your while loop in your code. Try putting it outside.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would you create the same program without try and catch, relying solely on Scanner? Would this be possible?

Comment: Yes, put throws IOException after the main, like you already have. That should do it.

Comment: By the way, if you put the outfile.close() outside of your for loop, it does write the numbers to your file.

Comment: I tried putting it outside the for loop and it seems that my variables won't increment.

Comment: Clarify again what you are trying to do. Generate 1000 random numbers, write them to a file, and if it's 0 increment squirrelFox?

Comment: I want to generate 1000 trials and with each trial generate enough random numbers until a 0 occurs. When a 0 occurs increment foxSquirrel and squirrelsSeen and when a 0 does not occur, increment squirrelsSeen.

Comment: How does this answer the question when the OP wants to write one line then read one line?

Answer (score 2):

`new PrintWriter(new File("squirrel.txt"))` immediately erases the file.  From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E%28java.io.File%29):

> If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file will be created.

It is not possible to read and write the same file simultaneously.  (Actually there are some cases were it’s possible, but they don’t apply here.)

Do not create your PrintWriter until you have finished reading from the file and have called `inFile.close()`.  Or, write to a different file, then when you’re done, rename it to match the original file.

Comment: Yes, your PrintWriter creates a file with zero size.  Your PrintWriter creates an empty file.  There is nothing to read.

Comment: So does that mean outFile.println(squirrelNum); doesn't print random numbers on to outFile?

Comment: inFile and outFile each have their own file positions.  inFile does not know that outFile has printed to the file.  Reading and writing to the same file is not supported behavior.  Even if you got it to work, it would be mostly luck, and would likely fail on other runs and when run on other computers.